# How do I get my angular site to render in the root and not in a folder?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have my Angular 4 site running great, but it runs in the ~/app/ folder.  So it appears in **http://example.com/app** but I simply want it to show up at **http://example.com**

Right now I have :

**package.json**

```
ng build --base-href /app/
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
  "outDir": "./../app"
```

Which works great, but if I change these to (which seems like it would work):

**package.json**

```
ng build --base-href /
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
  "outDir": "./../"
```

It won't render in the root - what am I missing?!  Thank you!

**EDIT**
Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my src/tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am realizing now that I might want it to be in its own folder, but just appear that it is at the root, that will work fine too!

Comment: Did you use `base` tag in html?

Comment: Try removing base href from your html. Add this `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },`  to your app.module.

Comment: Also can you provide your tsconfig files? `src/tsconfig.app.json` and `your_root/tsconfig.json`

Comment: not sure what is meant by "base href" and base tag? (new to this config stuff)

Comment: If you are using the angular cli it sets `<base href="/">` in index.html or whatever .html file your server is pointing to. Try removing that and set the base href in app.module under `providers: []` .. `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },` I am not sure if that will work for you or not as every environment is a little different. That works for us anyways. Also if you do that you shouldn't have to use this flag `--base-href ` when building.

Comment: that index.hmtl file is auto-generated and with our deployment strategy I can't change it

Comment: Does it have `<base href="/">` ?

Comment: now ng build gives me ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'D:\my_directory' - as it looks like it's trying to remove my base dir.  If it is in the app folder, that is fine, just so it appears it is not!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147293/discussion-between-kris-hollenbeck-and-naspinski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the angular cli it sets `<base href="/">` in **index.html** or whatever .html file your server is pointing to. Try removing that and set the base href in **app.module** under `providers: []` .. `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }`,

I am not sure if that will work for you or not as every environment is a little different. That works for our team anyways. Also if you do that you shouldn't have to use this flag --base-href when building.